# Need regular expression for restricting special characters

Tags: regex, oracle, sql-loader

I need to replace the following special characters with empty string.

```
™,®,',(TM),(R),é,�,’,–,â€
```

I was using     `trim(regexp_replace(:DESC, '(*[\\™®])', ' '))`

But it was failing. Tool is Sql Loader.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what's you tool? bash? python? java?

Comment: show your trials before you start getting the downvotes :p

Comment: @طاهر the tool is mentioned it's the apple developer library (he may have added that after your comment)

Comment: Added the info in question

Comment: @Dreamwalker: I don't think that's right.  Many newcomers use the [tag:nsregularexpression] tag to mean regexes in general, not realizing that it applies only to the class with that name in the Apple lib.  According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html), SqlLoader uses the POSIX ERE flavor.  I'm going to retag it.

Comment: @AlanMoore ok I just never spotted that before

Comment: Oracle actually uses a limited and slightly different sub-set of both POSIX and Perl flavours @Alan (though doesn't always combine them well).

Comment: @Ben: The crux of my comment is that it doesn't support non-capturing groups, which means both of the answers posted so far won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
[™�®'’é–]|â€|\((?:TM|R)\)
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fD4pC2/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:[™®'é�’–â€]|\(TM\)|\(R\))
```

replace with   <---empty space or nothing

should be enough for you

demo here: http://regex101.com/r/nG4qX4/2